# Greatest common divisor in java using prime factorizations

Tags: java, prime-factoring, greatest-common-divisor

```
        int a;
        int b;
        int iloscA = 0;
        int iloscB = 0;
        ArrayList liczbyPierwszeA = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList liczbyPierwszeB = new ArrayList();
        Scanner liczba = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Podaj a.");
        a = liczba.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Podaj b");
        b = liczba.nextInt();
        int a1 = a;
        int b1 = b;

        for (int i = 2; i <= a; i++) {

            while (a % i == 0) {
                // System.out.print(i + "*");
                liczbyPierwszeA.add(iloscA, i);
                iloscA++;
                a = a / i;
            }
        }

        int x = 0;
        System.out.print("Rozkład na czynniki pierwsze liczby " + a1 + "=");
        while (x < liczbyPierwszeA.size()) {
            System.out.print(liczbyPierwszeA.get(x) + "*");
            x++;
        }

        for (int i = 2; i <= b; i++) {

            while (b % i == 0) {
                // System.out.print(i + "*");
                liczbyPierwszeB.add(iloscB, i);
                iloscB++;
                b = b / i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
        int y = 0;
        System.out.print("Rozkład na czynniki pierwsze liczby " + b1 + "=");
        while (y < liczbyPierwszeB.size()) {
            System.out.print(liczbyPierwszeB.get(y) + "*");
            y++;
        }

        int licznik = 0;
        ArrayList Wspolne = new ArrayList();
        int WspolneLicznik = 0;
        while (liczbyPierwszeA.get(licznik) == liczbyPierwszeB.get(licznik)) {
            Wspolne.add(WspolneLicznik, liczbyPierwszeA.get(licznik));
            licznik++;
            WspolneLicznik++;
        }
        System.out.println("");
        int z = 0;
        while (z < Wspolne.size()) {
            System.out.print(Wspolne.get(z) + "*");
            z++;
        }
    }
}
```

Soory for the big block of code, but wanted to post all I have so far. Prime factorization works fine, now I wanted to compare both arraylists and find common elements. But for example with 36 and 48 it is

```
Rozkład na czynniki pierwsze liczby 36=2*2*3*3*
Rozkład na czynniki pierwsze liczby 48=2*2*2*2*3*
2*2*
```

And it doesn't work right as you can see, result should be 2*2*3, not 2*2. How to find common series of numbers in whole arraylist, not in the beginning of arraylist like my code works right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your while loop only finds the common prefix of the two lists. In order to find all the common elements, you need to iterate over the two `List`s using two indices :

```
    int indexA = 0;
    int indexB = 0;
    while (indexA < liczbyPierwszeA.size () && indexB < liczbyPierwszeB.size()) {
        if (liczbyPierwszeA.get(indexA) == liczbyPierwszeB.get(indexB)) {
            Wspolne.add(WspolneLicznik, liczbyPierwszeA.get(indexA));
            indexA++;
            indexB++;
            WspolneLicznik++; // not sure what this counter is for. I kept it just 
                              // in case it's needed
        } else {
            if (iczbyPierwszeA.get(indexA) < liczbyPierwszeB.get(indexB))
                indexA++;
            else
                indexB++;
        }
    }
```

I'm assuming the numbers in both `List`s are sorted in ascending order, which I think is a correct assumption (if I understood your code correctly).

EDIT :

Also change the declaration of your Lists to be parameterized :

```
    ArrayList<Integer> liczbyPierwszeA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> liczbyPierwszeB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Or even better :

```
    List<Integer> liczbyPierwszeA = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<Integer> liczbyPierwszeB = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Comment: It gives me error 'The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object'code' in line 'if (LiczbyPierwszeA.get(indexA) < liczbyPierwszeB.get(indexB))' Why? Those are numbers so why can't I use <?

Comment: @EyeMaze Change the declaration of your Lists to `ArrayList<Integer>`. A raw `ArrayList` type can contain any Object.

Comment: @EyeMaze My mistake. I forgot to change the index to `indexA`. Fixed now.

Comment: Okay, now it works. Thank you very much for you help. //yeach, I've noticed and fixed what was wrong :)